# Best way to speed up the process of adding values to an xarray dataset?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-xarray

I have four different variables that I want to add to one single array for plotting. They all come from a list of previously generated tuples called 'list_of_tuples'. There are thousands of values for each variable, so this is a large array:

```
variable_1 = np.array([x[0] for x in list_of_tuples])
variable_2 = np.array([x[1] for x in list_of_tuples])
variable_3 = np.array([x[2] for x in list_of_tuples])
time = np.array([x[3] for x in list_of_tuples])
```

I then take these variables and add them to an xarray dataset:

```
xarray_object = xr.Dataset({'variable_1': (['time'], variable_1), 'variable_2': (['time'], variable_2), 'variable_3': (['time'], variable_3), 'time': (['time'], time)})
```

This xarray object is so large, however, that it takes almost an hour to build the dataset. Do you have any suggestions for speeding things up?

Comment: I do not see how operating on few thousands items of an xarray can be so slow. Can you please make a fully [*reproducible* complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?